# Where to get BlackBerry CSK File for PhoneGap?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I want to use PhoneGap to sign my BlackBerry App. When I go to add the key files it asks for a CSK file.

[image]

I went to https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/ and requested keys.

However the files sent to me were 3 different CSI files(RBB, RCR, RRT).

How and where can I get the CSK and DB file needed to sign apps on PhoneGap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to install the [blackberry SDK](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download) (as part of Eclipse if you're using this IDE, otherwise get the standalone java one).

Then follow these [steps](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_publishing/Signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html).

Basically this will store your key locally, then you create a backup of it in the form of a .csk+.db files.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe® PhoneGap™ Build currently provides a default BlackBerry development version for all users, which provides an Over-The-Air install for your PhoneGap applications. However, to distribute your own BlackBerry applications, you will need to register with RIM for your own keys, and then import those keys into PhoneGap Build.

To register, fill out the form on  [RIM's site](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/) , and, once you receive your keys, follow the installation process locally.. using the steps [mentioned here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/blackberry-keys)