# Download Standard-Install for BlackBerry from Phonegap

Tags: blackberry, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm building a BlackBerry App using jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap. After I zip my project files and upload it to phonegap I get a list of platforms.

The BlackBerry file is listed as OTA install.

[image]

How can I download the Standard install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to download the standard install using the Phonegap website you must first provide PhoneGap with a signing key from BlackBerry.

Detailed instructions on getting the signing keys onto the PhoneGap website can be found in one of my previous questions. [Where to get BlackBerry CSK File for PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707859/where-to-get-blackberry-csk-file-for-phonegap)

After uploading the keys and rebuilding the button might still say OTA install but try clicking download because in my situation the download was Standard Install despite saying OTA install.

[image]